# Multiline select2 dropdown and bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, jquery-select2

How do I make a select2 dropdown multi-line when in the "closed" state i.e. show text over multiple lines and not truncate it with "..."

The example below is the current (incorrect) state. It also shows the dropdown as disabled - I get the same result in the enabled state.

[image: Example of current state]

The example below shows what happens if the 'multiple' option is enabled

[image: Example with 'multiple' option enabled]

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="visit_id" class="col-md-4 control-label">Visit Address</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="visit2 form-control" id="visit_id" name="visit_id"><option value="4" selected="selected">79681 Noel Rapid, Suite 107, Apt. 918, Suite 639, Rennerbury, 51356-7440, Mexico</option></select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('visit_id') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    {!! Form::label('visit_id', 'Visit Address', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {!! Form::select('visit_id', $addresses, null, ['class' => 'visit2 form-control']) !!}
        {!! $errors->first('visit_id', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".visit2").select2().prop("disabled", true);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Major aside, but my suggestion, to help the non-Laravel people who will see this question (because your use of Laravel has literally nothing to do with this as far as I can tell) is to remove the Laravel/Blade from your example HTML. Create a reduced test case in pure HTML and post that to help people who want to help you.

Comment: @alexrussell added HTML version

Comment: Good stuff - next question: as far as I can tell you are saying you'd like to disable it but keep it showing as multiline, so the question is: can you make it show as multiline when it's *not* disabled? I didn't realise select2 even did that.

Comment: @alexrussell even when enabled, select2 will disable word wrap and truncate what it shows (with "...")

Comment: That's what I thought. So what exactly is your question? It sounds like you're asking for something that may not be doable, but phrasing it in such a way that it makes people think it should be. That is to say, the way i read it at least, you're kinda suggesting that when *not* disabled it's all good, but when disabled it's not playing ball, but that doesn't appear to be the case from your answers above. So it just may be that Select2 can't handle multiline full stop, not just when disabled. But maybe I'm reading your question amazingly incorrectly.

Comment: @alexrussell updated question to be clearer

Comment: Ahh that makes much more sense. As for finding an answer to your question I'm sorry but I don't know. At a guess, select2 just doesn't support showing as multiline and probably won't (unless you use the 'taggable' style select2 and limit it to 1 entry maybe, then it'll look like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/48yrwfl100ii155/Tokenised%20Multiline.png?dl=0) (link is temporary and will not work in a few days)).

Comment: @alexrussell updated to show what happens with the multiple option (cuts off still)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, because of your css, some tags, created by select2, are with the width set to 100%. So, to fix it, you can put this js after your select2 initialization:

```
$(".select2-search-field").css("width", "auto");
$(".select2-input").css("width", "auto");
```

I just don't remember if you have to use `"auto"`or `"intial"` instead.

Comment: Try to put a fix number to see if it works. For example: `.css("width", "200px");`